# SQL - Sum of Unique Values From Reused Column

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I need a sum of Shoes and Hats from a table containing a User, Filename, and Payload. Duplicate records should be ignored where a Duplicate Record is defined as the same User, Payload, and the portion of the Filename following the '/'. In the example table below, record #3 is a duplicate of record #2 using the rules above. The desired result is a sum of Shoes and a sum of Hats, example below.

**Example Data**

```
+---+------+----------+-----------+
| # | User | Filename |  Payload  |
+---+------+----------+-----------+
| 1 | A    | a/123    | Shoes = 3 |
| 2 | A    | a/123    | Hats = 2  |
| 3 | A    | b/123    | Hats = 2  |
| 4 | B    | a/123    | Shoes = 1 |
| 5 | B    | a/123    | Hats = 1  |
+---+------+----------+-----------+
```

**Expected Output**

```
+-------+------+
| Shoes | Hats |
+-------+------+
|     4 |    3 |
+-------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive happens to support `substring_index()`, so you can do:

```
select sum(case when payload like 'Shoes%'
                then substring_index(payload, ' = ', -1)
                else 0
           end) as num_shoes,
       sum(case when payload like 'Hats%'
                then substring_index(payload, ' = ', -1)
                else 0
           end) as num_hats
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user, payload, substring_index(filename, '/', -1)
                                order by user
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

I strongly suggest that you change your data model and not store the payload as a string.  Numbers should be stored as numbers.  Names should be stored as names.  They should not be combined in a string, if that can be avoided.